# Python grpc-tools is declared to be missing right after I installed it

Tags: python, ubuntu, grpc, grpc-python

I'm using the very latest Ubuntu 21.04 for aarch64. In order to experiment with gRPC, I installed grpc stuff:

```
python3 -m pip install grpc
python3 -m pip install grpcio-tools
```

I also tried:

```
pip3 install grpc
pip3 install grpcio-tools
```

These appeared to be successful however when I tried to generate my gRPC Python code from the .proto file, I was told by the system that grpcio-tools is not installed.

How to fix this? Is Ubuntu for aarch64 just broken?

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem was that I used python instead of python3 when executed the generation:

```
python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc --help
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to an ARM64 instance and so can't repro this.

According to [Running gRPC and Protobuf on ARM64 (on Linux)](https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-on-arm64/), it should be supported (with Python)

Please include in your question more details.

For me on Ubuntu 20.04 on an AMD64:

```sh
python -m grpc_tools.protoc --help
/usr/bin/python: No module named grpc_tools

python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate

python3 -m pip install grpcio grpcio-tools

Collecting grpcio
  Using cached grpcio-1.39.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (4.3 MB)
Collecting grpcio-tools
  Using cached grpcio_tools-1.39.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (2.5 MB)
Collecting six>=1.5.2
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from grpcio-tools) (44.0.0)
Collecting protobuf<4.0dev,>=3.5.0.post1
  Using cached protobuf-3.17.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.0 MB)
Installing collected packages: six, grpcio, protobuf, grpcio-tools
Successfully installed grpcio-1.39.0 grpcio-tools-1.39.0 protobuf-3.17.3 six-1.16.0

python -m grpc_tools.protoc --help

Usage: /${HOME}/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc_tools/protoc.py [OPTION] PROTO_FILES
Parse PROTO_FILES and generate output based on the options given:
...
```

And, I can run e.g. the [`hello-world` Python sample](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/python/helloworld)

Comment: At it happens I was trying to run a modified version of their hello world example. You could try running this in Qemu if you want to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after closing both VSCode and Terminal, and starting them again.

Comment: Did you do this on Ubuntu for aarch64? My computer is a raspberry pi 4.